# How do I suppress "Info:" in terminal when I have argparse?

Tags: python, scripting

I am currently running a python script through blender (with argparse using a custom argparser for blender) and I am wanting to clean up the terminal when it runs. It currently is outputting "Info:" quite a bit more than what I want (which is never). Is there a way to suppress the "info" but make it to where I till get error messages?

Here is my current way of running my script (whatever solution I need has to be done before argparse which is denoted after the --, so it would need to be before the --): blender --background --python myscript.py -- -argparse1 argparse1 -argparse2 argparse2

Anything helps!